# Critique My Website 

Tags: websites, portfolio, sound-design, advertising

Im starting a sound design business with a fellow college graduate. 
[here's our site](http://www.soundofsightaudio.com/)

I would love to hear any of your thoughts on the site design, and the way the videos are displayed. 
I created it at Wix.com. Its all flash based so I'm very curious about how the site loads on other peoples computers. 
If you have time and energy to help, I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

-Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool concept, everything works on my computer and it loads fine - I'm on a laptop.

Couple rough edges and honest advice (hey, you asked!):

Send button in the contact field is cut off on the bottom (the font is),

The font used on the top buttons is a bit plain and dry. By dry I mean in an audio sense like it's just dry and plain - no reverb on it, no excitement or life. I'd take the font you have and put it through a photoshop plug-in or something to give it depth or an effect. Maybe it's too low-fi? I do like the font you used or the bios for the team. That color fits with the background more to my eyes, the top buttons not so much.

I'd put links with a photo of the project as opposed to having the first one only to be seen and then you have to click the over arrow to see the other 2 samples - instead, I would put little pictures or the name of the project on the right hand side of the screen or something so people can choose and see what you've done at a glance as opposed to one only and then a "1 of 3" at the top - makes it look like you've done less IMHO.

The buttons when pressed have a bit of a low-fi feel to it like it's not fully loaded and boxy.

I like the photos in the background - the photo on top is hard to discern what it is, however.

In the contact page, some of the fields load with the text with spaces between letters and other fields don't - like Name, Email, Subject and Message. This looks a bit off to me.

Hope that helps - I'm by no means a pro site designer but I compared yours to other pro ones like my friends [Miguel Isaza's](http://designingsound.org/), [Colin Hart's](http://www.colinhartonline.com/), [Tim Prebble's](http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/), [Nathan Moody's](http://www.noisejockey.net/blog/), and this site. This site is a perfect example of simple yet professional. Check it out, do an A-B test and I think you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, your detailed critique is extremely helpful. I've been working on it for a while so its hard for me to have an objective view point. 
I wish there was an easy way to change the font of the menu names, I think It's going to require some photoshoping. 
That top photo is a picture of the west oakland port cranes. I'm in the east bay so i thought it was pretty fitting. I made them less blurry so maybe it'll be easier to discern. 
I'll look into the contact page, it shouldn't be like that. 
Thanks again! 

Answer (score 1):

Hi Kevin,

First of all, I would recommend you to start building visual identity for Sound of Sight. That mean: make logo, set default colors, choose font. It will help people to remember who or what is Sound of Sight.

Regarding your site. If your goal is only to make web PRESENTATION then Flash is good, but if you want more advanced web SITE then you should consider html, php or asp. Google and other search engines can not index sites that are build in Flash. My advice is either to add blog or to make whole site in [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com/). It is easy to use, many templates are available and support many advanced things ( audio, video, youTube, Vimeo….) and the best thing it is search engine friendly. If you considering this also look this question: [How to set up a personal website?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/4724/how-to-set-up-a-personal-website)

Video on your site are slow loading and you put some kind of placeholder so that your visitor know that there is something and they should wait. Also try to put thumbnails of video and description on side or under.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: +1 to this advice.  wordpress is incredible, easy to manage, etc.  even paying for a good template isn't that big of an expense - you can get a very nice one for under $100.  I also highly recommenda corporate contest at www.worth1000.com - that's where I got my logo and I was thrilled with the results for the price.

Answer (score 1):

Best of luck with the new venture! I'm also a graphic and web designer. Aesthetics aside, the entire site is Flash, and thusly, not viewable on the iPad/iPhone/iPod at all. Thing is, there's nothing going on that couldn't easily be achieved with plain old HTML and CSS. Looking at your source code it appears you've got alternative HTML in there, which helps your SEO - but then why the whole site in Flash at that point? Flash-only locks out a lot of the traffic on the web these days. Maybe not worth it, especially if it's not providing any special functionality. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I agree, HTML/CSS all the way - and only Java/AJAX when necessary for a specific function.

Answer (score 0):

Using Safari 5.0.3 and your audio loads for your video, but no video. If you are using wix, make sure the sizing of video is not larger than the boundary of the "moving page" area, otherwise the video will not show up. Had this problem on my end a couple months ago. Just double check - it could be something else. Layout is cool though!